# Using mouseClicked and mouseDragged at the same time

Tags: java

I am trying to use mouseClicked and mouseDragged in java at the same time. But mouseClicked belongs to MouseListener and mouseDragged belongs to MouseMotionListener. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No information on what you've tried or anything

Comment: @KeithEnlow No explanation is not the nature of the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

For convience, you could take a look at [`MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) which implements `MouseListener`, `MouseMotionListener` and `MouseWheelListener`

```
MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MosueEvent evt) {
        // Do what ever here
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MosueEvent evt) {
        // Do what ever here
    }
}

yourComponent.addMouseListener(ma);
yourComponent.addMouseMotionListener(ma);
```

See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details

Equally, you could create you own class...

```
public class MyAwesomeMouseHandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    // Implement the required methods...
}
```

Then you would simply create an instance add register them...

```
MyAwesomeMouseHandler handler = new MyAwesomeMouseHandler();

yourComponent.addMouseListener(handler);
yourComponent.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
```

You you could just implement the listeners separatly and register them separatly...